# Assigning abilities in Laravel 5.1 Authorization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Recently upgraded to Laravel 5.1 and have read the new features which is [Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#introduction) .  I was using Entrust before but decided to use this now as I was using a very basic permission/abilities anyway.  The doc explains how to define and check for abilities but I didn't find a line to attach this ability to a certain user.  Am guessing these abilities should be saved and pulled from the db, but not sure how to attach these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `Authorization` service doesn't assign abilities/permissions coming from a database. The docs seem to mislead us in that direction.

You can opt for a package to deal with this part, such as https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission